# How to make resource library support inteli-sense in wpf,like MahMetro or MaterialDesign Toolkit?

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary, mahapps.metro, material-design-in-xaml

I am working on a complicate project which contains too much resources,custom controls and usercontrols.I extracted all resouces,such as brushes,images,styles...to a independend project. It works.In my main project and other modules ,I can use resources in the refrenced project.

But, when I build the resouce project to a dll,then main project refrence the dll(not project),I can't get inteli-sence support.

On the other side,when I use MahMetro,or MaterialDesign by nuget,I do get inteli-sence support.

In the two scenerios,I use external resource libs(mine and MahMetro/MaterialDesign's) through pack sytax,such as:

```
 <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/{DllName};component/{DllPath}/{resourceDictionaryNam}.xaml" />
```

So,Am I lost anything when I build resource lib?I want to know why MahMetro and MaterialDesign can support inteli-sense.

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a DesignTimeResources.xaml ResourceDictionary in the Properties folder of your WPF project.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="PathToTheDictionary"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

You will also need to edit the .csproj and to include your resource dictionary

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Page Include="Properties\DesignTimeResources.xaml">
    <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    <ContainsDesignTimeResources>true</ContainsDesignTimeResources>
  </Page>
</ItemGroup>
```

More here: https://antonymale.co.uk/design-time-resources-in-wpf.html

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I will try the method later. I guess it will work. But I want more.You know,when you use Metro or Materialdesign ,you don't need do anything in you main project.I want realize that effect.